# PHP: Three images from database in a row

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, row

I would like to display three images from the database in one row. At the moment, all the images are in a vertical line and I do not know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. I am only learning PHP, have checked other questions and they have been no help.

I have tried using Bootstrap however that has not worked either. The way I have it does display 3 in a row however, shoes the same product in each row and only if I have the query `$show_men="SELECT model, id,  price,image FROM products WHERE id='id' "`

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <!--selecting products from database and displaying. when user clicks on more info button, information is stored in array and displayed on item.php-->
    <?php
    include 'mysql.php';
    $show_men="SELECT model, id,  price,image FROM products WHERE cat='men' ";
    $query_men=mysqli_query($conn,$show_men);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_men,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo '<br><br><table class="table"><tbody>
            <tr>
            <div><center><img class="img-responsive" src="../images/'.$row['image'].'" width="200" height="200"></center><br>
            <center><strong>'.$row['model'].'</strong><br><br><strong>Price:£    '.$row['price'].'</strong><br><br>
            <a href="../php/item.php?id1='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a><br><br><strong></center></div><hr>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>';

    }?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the column instead of the table..

```
    <div class="row">
            <?php

            include 'mysql.php';
             $show_men="SELECT model, id,  price,image FROM products WHERE cat='men' ";
             $query_men=mysqli_query($conn,$show_men);
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_men,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
             echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><br><br><table class="table"><tbody>
              <tr>
                <div><center><img class="img-responsive" src="../images/'.$row['image'].'" width="200" height="200"></center><br>
                <center><strong>'.$row['model'].'</strong><br><br><strong>Price:£    '.$row['price'].'</strong><br><br>
                <a href="../php/item.php?id1='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a><br><br><strong></center></div><hr>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table></div>';

             }
             ?>
     </div>
```

Comment: cool, it worked. thanks. cant pick best answer for another 11 mins

Comment: What's up with the downvote? Weasel too shy to comment?